# How to update the expandable listview while we click onBackPressed() method in Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable ListView. If i click the groupview ,I want to find the child size and if child size is zero ,then it will go to another activity,else it shows all the child view.

Here i have one problem with my code.For example if i child size is zero,then if i click the groupview ,it will go another activity.Then again i backpressed,then i click another group view,it shows the previous size of my child view that is the last group view shows(Size is zero).Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

```
public class ExpandableListActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
  int group_position,child_position;
  boolean flag=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);


        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {


                if(child_position == 0){

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ExpandableListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
//        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
//        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
//        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
//        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
//        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);


    }
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ExpandableListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

             child_position=this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                     .size();
             group_position=groupPosition;

            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);



            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `onGroupClick` to:

```
  @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {


                if(listAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0){

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ExpandableListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                return false;
            }
```

what i also noticed is that `group_position` is not used anywhere, infect you are not even assigning any value to it. If you have some use of `group_position` change following:

```
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

         child_position=this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                 .size();
        // group_position=groupPosition; <<<change to below>>>
         ExpandableListActivity.this.groupPosition=groupPosition;

        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }
```

Comment: Yes.You are correct.Thanks for your reply.I got the answer as you said.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it soled your problem ;-)